# How to make bread improver?

Tags: bread

For unknown reasons, but probably related to the covid pandemic, we are unable to buy bread improver.

Related question - [What is 'Bread Improver'?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11317/what-is-bread-improver)

Our daily bread is made in a bread machine, and our recipe is approximately 50% rye, 50% white (or sometimes wholemeal), salt, water and yeast.  Without the bread improver, it's still OK, but is about 30% larger "loaf~ier" with the improver included.

Is there some way of making your own bread-improver?  I found [these suggestions](https://www.restlesschipotle.com/5-ingredients-to-help-your-bread-rise-higher/), but I would have preferred more of the science behind the actions of the ingredient.

I think the main ingredient in our improver is Soy [Lecithin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lecithin).

Since lecithin is found in egg yolk, milk and soy beans.  I'd be happy to add all these to the bread, but I'm after a few hints before I go wasting good flour on ill-informed experimentation.

My current thought is to start with maybe a tablespoon (20ml) of skim milk-power added to the flour.  Does that sound reasonable?

EDIT: found a recipe: http://www.breadmachinedigest.com/recipes/enhancer-recipes/bread-freshtm-dough-enhancer.php I'm by no means a vegetarian, but I am also not particularly keen on adding gelatine to my bread.

Answer (score 1):

Vitamin C is probably the most critical of the components of most bread improvers. It helps the yeast grow essentially - just like you need vitamins, so does the yeast. Apparently it also strengthens the gluten through a chemical reaction.

Lecithin is also good to add. At the quantities provided in a typical lecithin additive to bread it acts as an [emulsifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulsion#Emulsifiers) - breaking down fats/oils supplied in the bread mixture and making them more available to the yeast, thereby enhancing metabolism, as well as improving moisture retention through better mixing of the fat/oil and water within the loaf.